# Ubuntu 15 network with bond, VLAN, bridge

Tags: server, kvm-virtualization

I am posting this question with the reply because I already find the answer after some searches and I think it could benefit other people since I didn't find easy to solve this on Ubuntu 15.

- Note 1: this question is also valid for Debian 8
- Note 2: the answer I post is a working solution but maybe not the best (I have not tweaked the bonding solution so more testing is needed here)
- Note 3: The question cover also 2 others minor questions:

  - How to enable DHCP on a bonding interface on Ubuntu 15?
  - How to enable WOL on Ubuntu 15?

Here is the question:
I am using Ubuntu 15 server, mostly to use KVM with more up to date packages than Debian 8. My setup is like this:

```
eth0 |
     |--> Bond -- VLAN --> bridge
eth1 |
```

How to I configure this setup in Ubuntu 15 server?

Answer (score 0):

So on ubuntu 15 server, I will use the "real" interface name (so, no ethx but the name givent by the bios vis systemd)

1- Enable the bond module for the kernel:

```
cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
loop
lp
#rtc
bonding
```

2 - Install necessary tools:

```
apt-get install vlan bridge-utils
```

3- reboot your server to be sure all is correct at this point. Note that you cancheck if the vlan and bonding module are loaded using:

```
lsmod | grep -E "bond|8021q"
8021q                  32768  0
garp                   16384  1 8021q
mrp                    20480  1 8021q
bonding               13926
```

4- Go to /etc/networking and make a copy of the interfaces file
5 - Here is the config I use to make it works:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#

allow-hotplug enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
        ethernet-wol g

allow-hotplug enp1s0f1
iface enp1s0f1 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
        ethernet-wol g

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
        slaves enp1s0f0 enp1s0f1
        bond-primary enp1s0f0
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-mode active-backup

#
auto bond0.200
iface bond0.200 inet manual
        vlan-raw-device bond0

#
auto vmbr200
iface vmbr200 inet static
        address 192.168.2.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.2.63
        gateway 192.168.2.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.2.1
        dns-search mydomnain.lan
        bridge_ports bond0.200
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 9
        up /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE up || /bin/true
```

5- Configure your switch to allow only vlan traffic on the ports where the 2 interfaces are connected (vlan trunck) (more on this later maybe :) )
6- if you only need dhcp on the bonding interface, use this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#

allow-hotplug enp1s0f0
iface enp1s0f0 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
        ethernet-wol g


allow-hotplug enp1s0f1
iface enp1s0f1 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
        ethernet-wol g


auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
        slaves enp1s0f0 enp1s0f1
        bond-primary enp1s0f0
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-mode active-backup
```

7- To enable WOL (wake on lan) on the 2 interface, note the line `ethernet-wol g` in the section of the 2 interfaces.

That's pretty all for now. I will tweak this question/post as soon as I have time toi play with LACP and bonding option as well as other setting found in the bridge parts. But it's a working solution for ubuntu 15 server and I hope it will help other people :)

Thanks